# Elasticsearch how to remove leading zeros from string

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to remove leading zeros from data inserted into Elasticsearch, but the data needs to be handled as string and not as number. For example, "*1234*", "*01234*" and "*01234test*" should all be handled. In this example, searching for "1234" should return 2 results.How can I achieve this? Is there a *filter* or *char_filter* I can use in the following mapping script?

```
{  
   "settings":{  
      "analysis":{  
         "analyzer":{
            "diacritical":{  
               "type":"custom",
               "tokenizer":"standard",
               "filter":[  
                  "standard",
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding",
                  "nfd_normalizer"
               ]
            }
         },
         "filter":{  
            "nfd_normalizer":{  
               "type":"icu_normalizer",
               "name":"nfc"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings":{  
      "testType":{  
         "_timestamp":{  
            "enabled":"true",
            "store":"yes"
         },
         "properties":{  
            "mynumber":{  
               "store":"yes",
               "type":"string",
               "index":"analyzed",
               "analyzer":"diacritical"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one approach would be to construct a [pattern replace filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern_replace-tokenfilter.html) which works on the tokens from standard tokenizer.

Something on these lines should work for the example in OP:

```
"leading_zero_trim":{
    "type":"pattern_replace",
    "pattern":"^0+(.*)",
    "replacement":"$1"
}
```

Example Settings:

```
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "diacritical": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "filter": [
                  "standard",
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding",
                  "nfd_normalizer",
                  "leading_zero_trim",
                  "trim_zero_length"
               ]
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "nfd_normalizer": {
               "type": "icu_normalizer",
               "name": "nfc"
            },
            "leading_zero_trim": {
               "type": "pattern_replace",
               "pattern": "^0+(.*)",
               "replacement": "$1"
            },
            "trim_zero_length": {
               "type": "length",
               "min": 1
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Test Analyzer:

```
get <index_name>/_analyze?analyzer=diacritical&text=hello omarta 01234 12340 123404 0001 000 0123test
```